# How can I fix tar-bzip2-ruined source code encoding?

Tags: c++, encoding, tar, clion, bzip2

I nearly completed a DES implementation for a school project when...

I ruined my source code with tar & bzip2.

The command was:
`tar cjvf des.cpp des.h main.cpp > des_implementation.tar.bz2`

I tried to create a compressed archive to send to a friend. To my horror, when I opened the source code in CLion (des.cpp, des.h, and main.cpp), I found that des.cpp was completely ruined and CLion was displaying an error:  `File was loaded in the wrong encoding: 'US-ASCII'`.

Here is a sample of the file's contents:
``` BZh91AY&SY©fZ�×ÿÐÞ°�ÀY÷ÿÝ¿ïßÊÿïÿê���PÞáÃ³``Í®:D4i¢4Òz¦5=OPÞ¤iâSÚ£@õ�å ```

I've also tried unzipping the zipped filed, but to no avail. I thought the command would create a separate .tar.bz file and leave the originals alone?

Main questions:

1. How did this happen?
2. How can I make sure it never happens again?
3. How can I fix this?

I am flustered and desperate, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For 2. [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) helps. It has other neat advantages, so maybe look into git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened because of the `f` option to `tar`, which specifies that the output file is `des.cpp`.

You can't make sure it never happens again, but you can mitigate it by using *version control*, *backups*, and [*reading manual pages*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) before using unknown commands.

And unless you had a backup lying around (or already are using version control), then there's really nothing you can do about it.